# Deny access to certain methods on an asmx to IP-addresses not in the company

Tags: authorization, ip-address, asmx

I have an asmx that contains different methods.
Some of those methods should be available to everyone.
Some only to computers from the company.

Is there a way to allow access to methods based on the IP-address used?